# stacking ajax requests

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

thanks for checking this out.

I have a database in mysql, which currently fills a drop down menu, which on select fills a second drop down using an ajax `xmlhttprequest` to a php file which runs a mysql query.

I'd like to then display a table based on the selection from the second drop down, whilst still leaving the first drop down functional.

So far I've tried adding a second js call to the main document, and also tried putting that js call into the output of the php file called by the first.

Neither option seems to work.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Logfiles never show it trying to get the getclubs.php so i'm assuming that the GetClub call is never getting triggered.

**Test.php :**

```
<html>
<title>
demo </title>
<head>
<script>
function GetCounty(str)
 {
 if (str=="")
   {
   document.getElementById("countymenu").innerHTML="";
    return;
    } 
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
      else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("countymenu").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","getcounty.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<script>
 function GetClubs(str)
 {
 if (str=="")
   {
   document.getElementById("clubtable").innerHTML="";
   return;
   } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
  else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
 {
 document.getElementById("clubtable").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
   }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","getclub.php?q="+str,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
  }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>


<?
 // Load field datas into List box
 $cn=mysql_connect("localhost","user","password") or die("Note: " . mysql_error());
 echo "Conn ok<br>";
 $res=mysql_select_db("snowusa_clubs",$cn) or die("Note: " . mysql_error());
 echo " Database opened<br>";
 //$rescounty=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM county WHERE state_id='33' ORDER by name;") or die ("Note: " . mysql_error());
    $resstate=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM state ORDER by longstate;") or die("Note: " . mysql_error());
echo " qry executed<br>";
 ?>
 <h1>Select</h1>


State:
 <select name="State" size=1 onchange="GetCounty(this.value)">
 <option value="">Select a State</option>
 <?
  while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($resstate))
 {
 echo "<option value=" .$rs['id'] . ">" . $rs['longstate'] . "</option>";
 }
 echo "</select> "
 ?>
 <p>
</p>
<div id="countymenu"><b>County menu for selected state will be listed here.</b></div>




 </body>
 </html>
```

**getcounty:php :**

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$cn=mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
if (!$cn)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

 mysql_select_db("snowusa_clubs", $cn);

 $sql="SELECT * FROM county WHERE state_id = '".$q."' ORDER by name";

 $result = mysql_query($sql);

 $fulllist="SELECT * FROM allclubs WHERE stateid = '".$q."' ORDER by clubname";
 $listresult = mysql_query($fulllist);




 echo "County : <select name=\"County\" size=1 onchange=\"GetClub(this.value)\">";

 echo "<option value=\"\">Select County</option>";

 while($rc = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
 echo "<option value=" .$rc['id'] . ">" . $rc['name'] . "</option>";
 }
 echo "</select>";

 echo "<p></p>";
 echo "Table of All Clubs in Selected State:</br>";

 echo "<table border='1'>
 <tr>
 <th>County</th>
 <th>Club Name</th>
 <th>Address</th>
 <th>Phone</th>
 <th>Website</th>
 <th>Email</th>

 </tr>";

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($listresult))
   {
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['county'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['clubname'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['website'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
     }
   echo "</table>";

   echo "<div id='clubtable'><b>Club Listing will appear as a table here.</b></div>";

   mysql_close($cn);
   ?>
```

**getclub.php**

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$cn=mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
if (!$cn)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

 mysql_select_db("snowusa_clubs", $cn);

$sql="SELECT * FROM allclubs WHERE countyid = '".$q."' ORDER by clubname";

$clubresult = mysql_query($sql);




echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>County</th>
<th>Club Name</th>
<th>Address</th>
<th>Phone</th>
<th>Website</th>
<th>Email</th>

</tr>";

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($clubresult))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['county'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['clubname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['website'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
   }
  echo "</table>";


 mysql_close($cn);
 ?>
```

Comment: onchange="GetClub..." without 's'. Your actual function name has 's', GetClubs.

Comment: that was it :) :smackhead:

Comment: Please note that `XMLHttpRequest` doen't properly work in IE7+ till 10. Instead you'd stop re-inventing the wheel and start using popular javascript library like `Jquery`

Comment: I don't understand. Why people don't use a good IDE?

Comment: @itachi what do you mean a good IDE ?, nvm , wikipedia'd :)

Comment: @itachi **Notepad++** works great

Comment: @metal_fan , this is my first run at ajax , I asked how to do what I wanted to do, someone said ajax, so I searched the web and ended up doing this based on what I read on w3schools.com . I'll look into jquery tonight.

Comment: it has nothing to do with IDE. Nothing can prevent people from writing crappy code in best IDE ever

Comment: @JohnMacKenzie that sounds good. But learn basic javascript syntax first. It's not that complex. Then switch to jquery

Comment: @JohnMacKenzie w3schools.com is not a good resource. http://w3fools.com

Comment: @metal_fan: it certainly prevents silly mistakes like `getclub` or `getclubs`. Even if i use a crappy long name for a function, with an good ide, i have no worries about its spellings and i can actually give my time in coding rather than finding out the missing a or s or x.

Comment: john, for ajax, if you have no objection in adding a library, go with jquery. Very easy plus cross browser it works. You don't need to write different codes for IE, chrome etc. Learn it. Life will be easier.

Comment: Will definitely take this advice :)  This is new territory for me... pretty much all the MYSQL , AJAX , PHP , so may as well learn it correctly first time :)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to reorganize the code following some small steps :

1. server side code response will be json data
2. make your client calls using jquery, avoid managing low level HTTP calls
3. render the code and add event handlers on the client using jquery handlers injection on the fly

some references on jquery :

```
- GET HTTP calls with : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/
- how to add a event : http://api.jquery.com/bind/
```

some examples :

simple GET HTTP call to test.php

```
$.get("test.php", function(data) {
  alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

adding a click to an element with id = foo

```
$('#foo').bind('click', function() {
  alert('User clicked on "foo."');
});
```

Comment: why would he use `.bind()` when he can use `.on()` ? As of jQuery 1.7, the `.on()` method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I'll have to look at these references and see if I can make sense of them :)

Comment: @RPM `$(..).on(..)` should only be used when we expect new `DOM` elements from the server response. The common way is `$("selector").click(function(){...})`